# Fluid mechanics cauchy's stress tensor

Tags: fluid-mechanics

Is cauchy's stress tensor symmetric always?Does this symmetricity  hold in accelerating and non-zero cross velocity gradient flow field?

Comment: Have a look here : http://homepages.engineering.auckland.ac.nz/~pkel015/SolidMechanicsBooks/Part_III/Chapter_3_Stress_Mass_Momentum/Stress_Balance_Principles_03_The_Cauchy_Stress_Tensor.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The symmetric property of stress tensor is generally proved through Moment of momentum on a fluid element

So it holds as long as momentum conservation and moment equilibrium are satisfied for that element.

Answer (score 1):

As @mustang says, the symmetry of the Cauchy stress is a direct consequence of the conservation of angular momentum.  However, angular momentum is not conserved in a non-inertial frame and one has to use an inertial frame of reference to take advantage of stress symmetry.